# Ruby on Rails 3 javascript_include_tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, calendar

When I have this as my javascript_include_tag in the head section `application.html.erb`:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
```

I can successfully use `disable_with` on `submit_tag`, but when I change it to:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"%>
<%= javascript_include_tag "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

..in order to use a jQuery calendar I cannot use `disable_with` anymore. It doesn't work anymore.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing rails.js add that as well to your includes

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "rails" %>
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. It appears that to have the disable_with work I need at a minimum the "prototype" and "rails"  include tags but as soon as I add the 2 jquery include tags for the calendar, the calendar will work but the disable_with stops working <%=  javascript_include_tag  "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"%>
  <%=  javascript_include_tag  "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js" %>

Comment: Are you using prototype in your app or jquery? If you want to use jquery exclusively maybe you need to add the jquery-rails gem to your gemfile and try this.